# How does Outlook cope with IMAP server change (MX)

Tags: outlook, mx-record, imap

What happens with an Outlook local inbox when there happens to be an IMAP server change (MX change) and the new IMAP server/mailbox is blank? 
Will Outlook retain already downloaded messages in it's data file and resync them with the new server or will it just pull on blank and loose them all?

Comment: `What happens with an Outlook local inbox when there happens to be an IMAP server change (MX change)` - These are two unrelated things. The IMAP protocol doesn't have anything to do with the MX DNS record for a domain.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook over IMAP is a local cache, you will lose data if you switch servers without syncing data.

There are many open source and paid sync programs, imapsync, larch, bittitan, etc...